# Automatically get the error message instead of the outcome

Tags: php, html

I am making a page where you can calculate all kinds of stuff but can't get the one for circles to work the way its supposed to right now it keeps saying that the input is incorrect while nothing has been selected yet and it doesn't calculate anything at all it just refreshes the page and it should be instead returning the outcome of the conversion.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styling.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Calculator and Converter</header>
<div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#">TBD</a>
    <a href="#">TBD</a>
    <a href="#">TBD</a>
</div>
<content>
    <form method="POST">
        This converter is for circles
        <input type="number" name="input" placeholder="">
        <select name="circles" class="meters">
            <option value="radius">Radius</option>
            <option value="diameter">Diameter</option>
            <option value="circumference">circumference</option>
        </select>

        <select name="convercircle" class="meters">
            <option value="radius">Radius</option>
            <option value="diameter">Diameter</option>
            <option value="circumference">circumference</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</content>

</body>
</html>


<?php
$input=$_POST[''];
$circles=$_POST[''];
$convercircle=$_POST[''];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($circles==['diameter'] && $convercircle==['radius']) {
        $output=$input*2;
        echo "The radius is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles==['circumference'] && $convercircle==['radius']) {
        $output=$input/2;
        echo "The radius is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles==['radius'] && $convercircle==['diameter']) {
        $output=$input*2;
        echo "The diameter is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles==['radius'] && $convercircle==['circumference']) {
        $output=$input*2*3.14;
        echo "The circumference is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles==['diameter'] && $convercircle==['circumference']) {
        $output=$input*3.14*2;
        echo "The circumference is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles==['circumference'] && $convercircle==['diameter']) {
        $output=$input*3.14*2;
        echo "The diameter is $output";
    }
    else {
        echo "Please select a circle and a conversion";
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `$input=$_POST[''];` to do? The key in `$_POST` has to be the name of an input. It should be `$input = $_POST['input']`. And the same for the other variables. And you should only set these variables when `$_POST['submit']` is set, so they should be inside the `if` block.

Comment: `$circles==['diameter']` why do you have square brackets around the string? The value of `$_POST['circles']` will be a string, not an array. All your comparisons are like this.

Comment: @Barmar something like this?                                               $input=$_POST['input'];
$circles=$_POST['radius'];
$circles=$_POST['diameter'];
$circles=$_POST['circumference'];
$convercircle=$_POST['radius'];
$convercircle=$_POST['diameter'];
$convercircle=$_POST['circumference'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're missing the array keys when you set the variables from `$_POST`.
2. When you're comparing the variables, you have `[]` around the strings. That puts the string in an array, but the values of the variables are just strings. Don't do that.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $input=$_POST['input'];
    $circles=$_POST['circles'];
    $convercircle=$_POST['convercircle'];

    if ($circles=='diameter' && $convercircle=='radius') {
        $output=$input*2;
        echo "The radius is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles=='circumference' && $convercircle=='radius') {
        $output=$input/2;
        echo "The radius is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles=='radius' && $convercircle=='diameter') {
        $output=$input*2;
        echo "The diameter is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles=='radius' && $convercircle=='circumference') {
        $output=$input*2*3.14;
        echo "The circumference is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles=='diameter' && $convercircle=='circumference') {
        $output=$input*3.14*2;
        echo "The circumference is $output";
    }
    elseif ($circles=='circumference' && $convercircle=='diameter') {
        $output=$input*3.14*2;
        echo "The diameter is $output";
    }
    else {
        echo "Please select a circle and a conversion";
    }
}
```